# prove $\int_{-C}\vec{F}d\vec{R}=-\int_{C} \vec{F}d\vec{R}$

Tags: vector-analysis, contour-integration

> We need to prove $\int_{-C}\vec{F}d\vec{R}=-\int_{C} \vec{F}d\vec{R}$

Usual attempt in Textbook: Suppose $C:\vec{R(t)},a\leq t\leq b$. Then $-C:\vec{R(-t)},-b\leq t\leq -a$. I am able to verify the result. Can I define as $-C:\vec{R(a+b-t)},a\leq t\leq b?$

$\int_{-C}\vec{F}d\vec{R}= \int_{a}^{b}\vec{F}(a+b-t)\frac{d\vec{R}(a+b-t)}{dt}dt$
(putting $\tau=a+b-t$)
.
We get
$$-\int_{b}^{a}\vec{F}(\tau)\frac{d\vec{R}(\tau)}{d\tau}d\tau=\int_{a}^{b}\vec{F}(\tau)\frac{d\vec{R}(\tau)}{d\tau}d\tau=\int_{C} \vec{F}d\vec{R}$$
($\because$ integration is independent of variables)
What happen to the negative sign? where is my mistake? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parametrization of the reverse path is correct.

There are two negative signs: one in comparing $d\vec R/dt$ with $d\vec R/d\tau$, and the other with $d\tau = -dt$. So you should have 
$$\int_b^a \vec F(\tau)\cdot \frac{d\vec R}{d\tau}\,d\tau = - \int_a^b \vec F(\tau)\cdot \frac{d\vec R}{d\tau}\,d\tau = -\int_C \vec F\cdot d\vec R.$$